# Different views for each table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently making an app as soon as it launches you choose from a table view of different car makes. What I can't figure out is how to perform a segue to different table views with models based on the make you chose. For example once you select Honda I want it to display another table view with every honda model, but as of right now even if you select nissan it still shows Honda models instead of nissan models. How can you have different segues and different table views for each cell in the array?

Thank you so much in advance for taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: You shouldn't have different table views or different segues for that use. You only need to go to one table view but populate it with data based on which row was selected.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I guess my next question would be how do I show that I have selected the specific cell and how to populate it?

Comment: You use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to find out what row was selected, and query your data source as to what item (Honda in your example) was chosen. Please read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS", it has a wealth of information on table views and navigating between them.

Comment: @rdelmar is there anyway you can show me an example of what you mean? I can't seem to figure it out, it's a little frustrating. I looked through the Table view programming guide as well. Every row I select shows the same results for the destination table view, how do I differentiate between the row selected? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't understand what you're not understanding. You differentiate what row was selected by looking at the indexPath that's passed in to didSelectRowAtIndexPath. In pseudo code, if indexPath.row == 0 then do x, else if indexPath.row == 1 do y, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it creates or pointing out different controller segue on which you're moving too.
you should try following method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

If you want to check than just you can check by:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifer"]) {

}
```